# how to prefetch parents of a child on mptt tree with django prefetch_related?

Tags: django, prefetch, mptt

Say, I've got a product instance. Product instance linked to 4th level child category. If I only want to get root category and 4th level child category the query below is enough to fetch data with minimum database queries:

```
Product.objects.filter(active=True).prefetch_related('category__root',
                                                     'category')
```

If I have to reach parents of this product's category and using `get_ancestors()` method for this, nearly three times mode database query happening.

If I write query like below instead using `get_ancestors()` method, database queries stays low.

```
Product.objects.filter(active=True).prefetch_related(
    'category__root',
    'category', 
    'category__parent',
    'category__parent__parent',
    'category__parent__parent__parent',
    'category__parent__parent__parent__parent')
```

But this query is not effective when level of depth is unknown.
Is there a way to prefetch parents dynamically in the query above?

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I'll try to give it a go.

This will require an extra query though. (But that's better than the possible hundreds. - if not more.)

Some explanation;

**First:** We will need to determine how many levels deep the categories are for the active products.

To avoid the extra query every time, you could cache the following code at startup **if categories are static**.

```
max_level = Category.objects.filter(product_set__active=True)\ # Reverse lookup on product
    .values('level')\
    .aggregate(
        max_level=models.Max('level')
    )['max_level']
```

**Second:** We will need to create the prefetch string based on the levels. The maximum amount of levels is equal to the maximum amount of parents.

```
level 0 = no parents
level 1 = 1 parent
level 2 = 2 parents (nested)
level 3 = 3 parents (nested)
```

This means that we can easily loop over the `range` of the levels, and append the parent (string) to a list.

```
prefetch_string = 'category'
prefetch_list = []
for i in range(max_level):
    prefetch_string += '__parent'
    prefetch_list.append(prefetch_string)
```

**Third:** We pass in the `prefetch_list`, also unpacking it.

```
Product.objects.filter(active=True).prefetch_related(
    'category__root',
    'category', 
    *prefetch_list) # unpack the list into args.
```

---

We can then easily refactor this into a single dynamic function.

```
def get_mptt_prefetch(field_name, lookup_name='__parent', related_model_qs=None): 
    max_level = related_model_qs\
            .values('level')\
            .aggregate(
                max_level=models.Max('level')
            )['max_level']
    prefetch_list = []
    prefetch_string = field_name
    for i in range(max_level):
        prefetch_string += lookup_name
        prefetch_list.append(prefetch_string)
    return prefetch_list
```

And then you can get the prefetch list with:

```
prefetch_list = get_mptt_prefetch(
    'category',
    related_model_qs=Category.objects.filter(product_set__active=True), # To only get categories which contain active products.
)
```

https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical_details.html#level